# typo3 different title in second menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i have to build an page with two menus. And in the second menu, i need different titles. 
I had the idea to use the alternativ navigation-title. Is it possible to enable this in the first menu and disable in the second?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by overwriting the stdWrap.cObject:

```
lib.menu1 = HMENU
lib.menu1.1 = TMENU
lib.menu1.1.NO = 1

lib.menu2 = HMENU
lib.menu2.1 = TMENU
lib.menu2.1.NO = 1
lib.menu2.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject = COA
lib.menu2.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.10 = TEXT
lib.menu2.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.10.field = nav_title // title
# = use nav_title field if available or title field as fallback
# also other fields are possible, e.g. subtitle
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first menu set

```
NO.stdWrap.cObject = COA
NO.stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = title
```

and in your second menu

```
NO.stdWrap.cObject = COA
NO.stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = subtitle
```